# Array output from Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a model that will detect "Tables" in images and return their coordinates and number of columns and rows.
Input data:

```
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(fileName, target_size=(842, 595))
x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
```

Labels:

```
y = [-28.64, 12.0, 472.36, 195.0, 6, 4, -7.45, 128.61, 493.55, 282.39, 4, 3, -7.45, 231.62, 493.55, 485.38, 3, 7, -35.82, 501.0, 465.18, 684.0, 5, 4, 1.93, 614.0, 484.16, 819.0, 5, 5, -7.85, 769.0, 493.95, 906.0, 5, 2, -7.45, 1157.0, 493.55, 1338.0, 5, 4]
```

For each table in the image I have 6 values: [left, top, right, bottom, columns, rows] (repeated for each table)

Data loading:

```
def getRecordData(fileName):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(fileName, target_size=(842, 595))
    x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    y = []
    with open(fileName.replace('.png', '.tables.out')) as outFile:
        data = outFile.read().split('\n')
        if len(data)>0:
            for index in range(len(data)//6):
                y.append(float(data[index*6]))
                y.append(float(data[index*6+1]))
                y.append(float(data[index*6+2]))
                y.append(float(data[index*6+3]))
                y.append(int(float(data[index*6+4])))
                y.append(int(float(data[index*6+5])))   
        return x, y

def getRecords(fileNames):
    inputs = []
    labels = []
    for fileName in fileNames:
        x, y = getRecordData(fileName)
        inputs.append(x)
        labels.append(y)
    return np.array(inputs), np.array(labels)

def getData(input_dir):
    supported_formats = ['*.png']
    filenames = []

    for extension in supported_formats:
        pattern = os.path.join(input_dir, extension)
        filenames.extend(glob.glob(pattern, recursive=False)) 


    random.seed(args.seed)
    random.shuffle(filenames)

    num_test = int(args.split_ratio * len(filenames))


    inputs, labels = getRecords(filenames[num_test:])
    tests, testlabels = getRecords(filenames[:num_test])

    return inputs, labels, tests, testlabels
```

Model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (101,101), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', input_shape= shape),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='linear'),
        layers.Dense(6, kernel_initializer='normal')
    ])

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_absolute_percentage_error,
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse','accuracy'])
```

When running:

```
history = model.fit(trainData, trainLabels, epochs=EPOCHS,
                    validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kerastrainer.py", line 143, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "kerastrainer.py", line 126, in main
    validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0)
  File "/home/ehalca/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 780, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/home/ehalca/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 363, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/ehalca/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3277, in __call__
    dtype=tensor_type.as_numpy_dtype))
  File "/home/ehalca/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I assume the problem is with the output layer.

Comment: Can you share the code which initializes the `trainData` variable?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal added data loading functions

Comment: The primary cause of the problem may be this ~> As you are iterating through the filenames to append the image and label, maybe one of the labels or image is empty. Hence, an empty array gets appended in the list. Now, when this list is passed to NumPy, it is unable to form an array of uniform shape ( since some elements are empty ).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, you're correct, my labels had different sizes